# What is the difference between IRP and CSR

Tags: spatial, randomness

In this presentation:
sorry I couldn't upload the presentation so this is another example:

https://www.e-education.psu.edu/geog586/l5_p13.html

They are using CSR and IRP interchangeably. I think CSR stands for Complete Spatial Randomness and is a result of Poisson distribution (?) but what is IRP? (what does is stand for, is it Poisson too etc.)

Many thanks,\
Graham

Comment: which presentation?

Comment: oops. I added a link to a source with IRP/CSR

Comment: A little googling shows that http://www.amazon.com/Geographic-Information-Analysis-David-OSullivan/dp/0470288574#reader_0470288574 seems to be the standard reference for CSR and IRP definition. Per p. 57 in the preview "The result is a dot map generated by the independent random process (IRP), sometimes called complete spatial randomness (CSR)."

Comment: Also see this other page on the same course site you linked https://www.e-education.psu.edu/geog586/l4_p8.html "the independent random process, or complete spatial randomness, operates according to the following two criteria when applied to point patterns:

    1. events occur with equal probability anywhere; and
    2. the place of occurrence of an event is not affected by the occurrence of other events."

Comment: so basically the same thing?

Comment: Exactly the same thing per those references.

Comment: Cheers Mark! Can't find the kudos button but... Like!

Comment: Cheers Mark! Can't find the kudos button but... Like!